# Find position of item in Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-view

Is there a way to find the position of an icon in the action bar?

I have used the code below:

```
final View actionBarView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android"));

if (actionBarView != null) {
    final View buttonInActionBar = actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
    if (buttonInActionBar != null) {
```

If, I set action_bar_menu_layout like this:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item"
        MyApp:actionProviderClass="my_provider"
        MyApp:showAsAction="always|withText|collapseActionView"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:title="@string/item_name"/>
```

so by using the collapseActionView flag, everything works. But without that flag the view is not found. It looks like only in that case the menu is build by using that id as the view id.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it.

I used:

```
mItemView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item));
```

then I registered a GlobalLayoutListener and in the listener:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mItemView.getLocationInWindow(mMyItemLocation);
        if (mItemView == null || mMyItemLocation[0] == 0  || mItemView.getRight() == 0 || mItemView.getWidth() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        mLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
```